# Diferença entre CROSS APPLY e OUTER APPLY?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Qual é a diferença entre `CROSS APPLY` e `OUTER APPLY`? Como funcionam? Em qual situação podem ser usadas? Seria possível mostrar alguns exemplos?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`APPLY` é um comando análogo ao `JOIN`, só que para funções (`FUNCTIONS`).

Segundo o [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx):

> O operador APPLY permite que você invoque uma função com valor de tabela para cada linha retornada por uma expressão de tabela externa de uma consulta. A função com valor de tabela age como a entrada à direita e a expressão de tabela exterior age como a entrada à esquerda. A entrada à direita é avaliada para cada linha da entrada à esquerda e as linhas produzidas são combinadas na saída final. A lista de colunas produzida pelo operador APPLY é o conjunto de colunas na entrada à esquerda, seguido pela lista de colunas retornadas pela entrada à direita.
>
> Há duas formas de APPLY: CROSS APPLY e OUTER APPLY. CROSS APPLY só retorna linhas da tabela exterior que produzem um conjunto de resultados da função com valor de tabela. OUTER APPLY retorna linhas que produzem um conjunto de resultados e linhas que não o fazem, com valores NULL nas colunas produzidas pela função com valor de tabela.

Suponha as tabelas:

```
--Create Employees table and insert values.
CREATE TABLE Employees
(
    empid   int         NOT NULL
    ,mgrid   int         NULL
    ,empname varchar(25) NOT NULL
    ,salary  money       NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT PK_Employees PRIMARY KEY(empid)
);
GO
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES(1 , NULL, 'Nancy'   , $10000.00);
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES(2 , 1   , 'Andrew'  , $5000.00);
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES(3 , 1   , 'Janet'   , $5000.00);
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES(4 , 1   , 'Margaret', $5000.00);
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES(5 , 2   , 'Steven'  , $2500.00);
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES(6 , 2   , 'Michael' , $2500.00);
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES(7 , 3   , 'Robert'  , $2500.00);
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES(8 , 3   , 'Laura'   , $2500.00);
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES(9 , 3   , 'Ann'     , $2500.00);
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES(10, 4   , 'Ina'     , $2500.00);
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES(11, 7   , 'David'   , $2000.00);
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES(12, 7   , 'Ron'     , $2000.00);
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES(13, 7   , 'Dan'     , $2000.00);
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES(14, 11  , 'James'   , $1500.00);
GO
--Create Departments table and insert values.
CREATE TABLE Departments
(
    deptid    INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ,deptname  VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
    ,deptmgrid INT NULL REFERENCES Employees
);
GO
INSERT INTO Departments VALUES(1, 'HR',           2);
INSERT INTO Departments VALUES(2, 'Marketing',    7);
INSERT INTO Departments VALUES(3, 'Finance',      8);
INSERT INTO Departments VALUES(4, 'R&D',          9);
INSERT INTO Departments VALUES(5, 'Training',     4);
INSERT INTO Departments VALUES(6, 'Gardening', NULL);
```

Suponha a seguinte função para recuperar uma subárvore da tabela `Employees`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_getsubtree(@empid AS INT) 
    RETURNS @TREE TABLE
(
    empid   INT NOT NULL
    ,empname VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
    ,mgrid   INT NULL
    ,lvl     INT NOT NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
  WITH Employees_Subtree(empid, empname, mgrid, lvl)
  AS
  ( 
    -- Anchor Member (AM)
    SELECT empid, empname, mgrid, 0
    FROM Employees
    WHERE empid = @empid

    UNION all
    
    -- Recursive Member (RM)
    SELECT e.empid, e.empname, e.mgrid, es.lvl+1
    FROM Employees AS e
      JOIN Employees_Subtree AS es
        ON e.mgrid = es.empid
  )
  INSERT INTO @TREE
    SELECT * FROM Employees_Subtree;

  RETURN
END
GO
```

Usando o seguinte comando:

```
SELECT D.deptid, D.deptname, D.deptmgrid
    ,ST.empid, ST.empname, ST.mgrid
FROM Departments AS D
    CROSS APPLY fn_getsubtree(D.deptmgrid) AS ST;
```

Obtém-se:

```
deptid      deptname   deptmgrid   empid       empname    mgrid       lvl
----------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ---------- ----------- ---
1           HR         2           2           Andrew     1           0
1           HR         2           5           Steven     2           1
1           HR         2           6           Michael    2           1
2           Marketing  7           7           Robert     3           0
2           Marketing  7           11          David      7           1
2           Marketing  7           12          Ron        7           1
2           Marketing  7           13          Dan        7           1
2           Marketing  7           14          James      11          2
3           Finance    8           8           Laura      3           0
4           R&D        9           9           Ann        3           0
5           Training   4           4           Margaret   1           0
5           Training   4           10          Ina        4           1
```

Answer (score 16):

Resumindo:
CROSS APPLY - Similar ao INNER JOIN
OUTER APPLY - Similar ao LEFT  JOIN

Pode usar os campos das outras tabelas referenciadas no Where, Funções, Usar Top.