# duvida de max sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou com uma dúvida sobre sql, to com uma query que eu quero trazer a resposta mais recente de um objeto, só que ta vindo sempre o historico, tentei sub query, e etc, max, mas nao deu certo, alguém pra helpar?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       c.contrato, 
       ca.razao_social, 
       cnpj, 
       ar.descricao, 
       oa.descricao,
       CASE ac.situacao
           WHEN '1'
           THEN 'SemPendencia'
           WHEN '2'
           THEN 'ComPendencia'
           WHEN '3'
           THEN 'não se aplica'
       END AS Situacao,
       ac.data_inclusao
--(
    --SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 (ac3.data_inclusao) from analise_contrato ac3 where ac3.codigo = ac.codigo order by ac3.data_inclusao desc) as datanova
--  (select *
--    FROM Protocolo_documentos_entrega pde2
--         LEFT JOIN protocolo_documentos pd2 ON pd2.codigo = pde2.cod_protocolo_documentos
--         LEFT JOIN protocolo p2 ON p2.codigo = pd2.cod_protocolo
--         JOIN Contrato c2 ON c2.codigo = p2.cod_contrato
--         JOIN Contratada ca2 ON ca2.codigo = c2.cod_contratada
--         JOIN Analise_contrato ac2 ON ac2.cod_contrato = c.codigo
--         JOIN Area_responsavel ar2 ON ar2.codigo = c2.cod_area
--         JOIN Objeto_analise oa2 ON oa2.codigo = ac2.cod_objeto_analise
--    WHERE c2.contrato = c.contrato
--          AND pde2.codigo = pde.codigo
--          AND ac2.codigo = ac.codigo
--          AND ac.data_inclusao = ac2.data_inclusao
--) AS DataInclusao
FROM Protocolo_documentos_entrega pde
     LEFT JOIN protocolo_documentos pd ON pd.codigo = pde.cod_protocolo_documentos
     LEFT JOIN protocolo p ON p.codigo = pd.cod_protocolo
     JOIN Contrato c ON c.codigo = p.cod_contrato
     JOIN Contratada ca ON ca.codigo = c.cod_contratada
     JOIN Analise_contrato ac ON ac.cod_contrato = c.codigo
     JOIN Area_responsavel ar ON ar.codigo = c.cod_area
     JOIN Objeto_analise oa ON oa.codigo = ac.cod_objeto_analise
WHERE c.cod_contratante = '152'
      AND pde.STATUS = 0
      AND c.STATUS = '0'
      AND c.contrato = '003/Renner'
GROUP BY pde.codigo, 
         c.contrato, 
         ca.razao_social, 
         ca.cnpj, 
         ar.descricao, 
         oa.descricao, 
         ac.situacao, 
         ac.data_inclusao, 
         c.codigo, 
         ac.codigo
ORDER BY oa.descricao;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você só quer que venha a primeira entrada? Se sim, porque não usar `LIMIT 1`

Comment: nao nao, a principio, eu queria que viesse um de cada objeto (campo descricao), ex, tem 3 alvaras anvisa, quero que ele considere um top 1 do mais recente

Comment: Ao menos para mim está difícil entender o problema. Recomendo fazer um exemplo mínimo verificável. Terá mais chances de responderem sua pergunta. Veja instruções aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . Nesta outra questão, também de SQL, o autor fez um EMV: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/498179/como-fazer-um-merge-no-sql-quando-a-vari%c3%a1vel-chave-se-repete-em-uma-das-tabelas . Pode servir de exemplo.

Comment: olha essa outra pergunta e veja se ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/498987/retornar-valor-m%c3%a1ximo-de-tabela-no-join-mysql/498997#498997

Answer (score -1):

Cara, se entendi bem, ao invés de fazer o join da tabela JOIN Analise_contrato ac, você precisa trabalhar com OuterApply.

Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
Outer apply (Select Top 1 ac.data_inclusao
             From   Analise_contrato AC
             Where 1=1
             And ac.cod_contrato = c.codigo
             Order by AC.data_inclusao Asc) Dt_include
```

Ai lá no select, precisaria colocar Dt_include.data_inclusao.

Talvez esse tópico aqui também possa te ajudar: [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13731/diferença-entre-cross-apply-e-outer-apply](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13731/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-cross-apply-e-outer-apply)